# OWLApi visitor pattern: get superClass axiom

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

Suppose we have this ontology:

```
Class A:
     equivalentTo: hasRel D

Class B:
     equivalentTo: A and hasRel C

Class C
Class D

ObjectProperty: hasRel
```

Using visitor pattern  get `hasRel C` axiom (as a `OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom`):

```
 OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom equivalentAxiom = owlOnt.equivalentClassesAxioms(B);

OWLObjectVisitor v = new OWLObjectVisitor() {

            public void visit(OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom ax) {
                ax.classExpressions().forEach(c -> c.accept(this));
            }

            public void visit(OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom ce) {
                String property = ce.getProperty().toString();
                String filler = ce.getFiller().toString();

                System.out.println(property);
                System.out.println(filler);

            }
        };

equivalentAxiom.accept(v);
```

but this code has no proper `visit` method to traverse class `A`.
 i need to have something like this as output:

```
hasRel D 
hasRel C
```

Comment: what prevents you from getting all subclass and equivalence axioms for A then? Or to speak more general, once you visit an atomic class in a intersection get those axiom? And then apply your visitor on all the superclass expression resp. the side of the equivalence axiom that is not the atomic class? By the way, this is more or less  basically creating some kind of structural reasoner. It's just programming but nothing OWL API specific. All the core methods are there, you just have to write the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, the visitor looks correct and should output what you need. However, you're applying it only to the axioms that contain `B`. Apply it to all equivalent classes axioms and see if it produces the expected result.

Edit: The visitor cannot access other axioms in the ontology without the ontology being made available to it - this is because `A` does not link to the axioms that use it; that relation is held in ontology indexes.

So the visitor needs to access the ontology and look up equivalent axioms that contain the named classes involved in your root axiom.

OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom equivalentAxiom = owlOnt.equivalentClassesAxioms(B);

OWLObjectVisitor v = new OWLObjectVisitor() {

```
        public void visit(OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom ax) {
            ax.classExpressions().forEach(c -> c.accept(this));
            ax.getNamedClasses().forEach(c -> owlOnt.equivalentClassesAxioms(c).forEach(q->q.accept(this)));
        }

        public void visit(OWLObjectSomeValuesFrom ce) {
            String property = ce.getProperty().toString();
            String filler = ce.getFiller().toString();

            System.out.println(property);
            System.out.println(filler);

        }
    };
```

equivalentAxiom.accept(v);

Comment: I need  to do that  somehow recursively. i'm not going to do that manually.so i'm looking forward a visitor class that applied to `B` and traverse all superClasses named in equivalent expression (`A`), and return `hasRel C ` -`hasRel D` as result